LWC wire method - does it run when one of its parameters gets a new value
I have a wire method in my components and it loads a scrollable list of workorders assigned to the logged in user on page load. I am trying to rerun this method on the click of a button which I am reading is only possible imperative methods and not wire methods.
Also I am reading that when the value of its parameter changes it reruns the wire method again, is that true?
Here is my wire method as of now -
@wire(callToApex, { accountId: '$accountId' })

I am checking if adding another parameter to the wire method and change its value on a button click would that rerun the wire method?
Want to check if the below will work-
@wire(callToApex, { accountId: '$accountId', randomNumber: '$randomNumber' })

handleClick() {
  this.randomNumber = Math.random();
}

Please advise!

Yes, what the documentation states is true. Did you see the refreshApex method? I've sometimes myself used a number that can be incremented (in special circumstances) to get fresh data, but to use a dedicated method is better for readability.

yes I am using the refreshApex method in other scenarios but for this scenario it is not working for me.

Parameters prefixed with $ are reactive. When the value of a reactive parameter changes, the wire method is automatically re-invoked.
